# Image not resizing - Bootstrap 4, Rails 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

This is driving me a little bonkers.  I'm using bootstrap 4 class `.img-fluid` which should make the image respond to the parent; https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/

`<div class="img-fluid"><%= image_tag(@coffeeshop.image_path) %></div>`

I'm using rails `image_tag` to call a file name path which is a field stored in my postgres db.  The image shows up just fine, but I cannot get it to resize correctly when viewed on mobile.

Would calling the image with standard html `<img src="" />` make a difference?  I would of course need to change my db field, but that's doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.img-fluid` class uses the parents full width:

```
.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

So you have to add `.img-fluid` class to the image itself:

```
<div>
  <%= image_tag(@coffeeshop.image_path, class: 'img-fluid') %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the class to the image itself, not the div that contains it.